# Newsletter with table inside table: padding not working

Tags: css, html-email, padding, newsletter

I had this newsletter http://jsfiddle.net/n5cGm/

with a container div to center the newsletter and to give it a background image,

OK, we experienced few problems with it when sending it, it changed from (browser)

[image]

to (Outlook): **check the logo** position; don't even bother the border radius. is only there for the browsers that support it; not important if not.

[image]

**And this is the second** (wrong for now) version I am trying with a table inside a table:

http://jsfiddle.net/9dchU/1/

which in Firefox works fine but embedded in jsfiddle not and in Outlook looks almost the same...

can you see the style that is messing the padding?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As some browsers, some e-mail clients neither able to display the border-radius parameter. I suggest, use image for the white background.

Comment: the border-radius is not important. it's only there for browsers that support it. thanks for the comment but i don't think that's an answer to the question..

Answer (score 0):

I would start over from scratch. You seem to have a tag that's either not closed, extra or useless. Let me explain, there is no point in using the tbody or th tags for emails. They cause rifts in designs every time I test. Your design is actually really simple. What you want to do is something like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font: Arial;">
<tr><td>
<img src="http://domain.com/top-image.gif" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px">
text text text
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<img src="http://domain.com/bottom-image.gif" />
</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Don't use background images for emails as they are not supported.**

Here's what you do instead:

[image]

Take a look at the above picture. Forget about the four corners you're going to crop in in 3 slices horizontally.

The top would be your top-image.gif

mid you can discard, that's where your text should go.

Finally the bottom slice will be your bottom-image.gif

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: please check my edit and the comment to the other answer. border-radius is not important. but thanks!

Comment: then forget about table radius and look at how I layed out my table. That should fix your style problem.

Comment: i am already using cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"

Comment: that's not important. Look at the table structure itself. don't use tbody and th. Here's a nice tutorial for tables in email: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2491/tables-in-html-emails-nesting/

Comment: i don't see how your code helps.. its a table with 3 rows :S thanks anyway